# Giving an error when a function is not called before

Tags: c++, initialization, preprocessor, assertions

I am trying to manage initialization functions in a C++-based application. I would like to:

- Make sure that `init_some_hw_peripherals()` (see below) only runs once even if `init()` is called more than once.
- Prevent a function `doPerform()` from being executed if another function `init_some_hw_peripherals()`previously is not called from the object.

I've thought of the following solution, which does not work (I do not get any error messages if not initialized). I know why it does not work and it makes perfect sense. But I would like to achieve what I mentioned using these type of definitions. I hope this information helps.

I would appreciate if you could help me manage this situation and give me some guidance.

Thanks in advance.

**Initialization**

```
void myClass::init(void)
{
#ifndef MY_INIT_
#define MY_INIT_
      init_some_hw_peripherals();
#endif
}
```

**Application**

```
void myClass::perform (void)
{
#ifndef MY_INIT_
#error "You havent initialized. Use myClass::init()"
#else
      doPerform();
#endif
}
```

**EDIT**: The problem with using private variables for me is that I have several classes that may call the init function. So I do not want to make it a private variable. That is why I stick with this kind of solution, knowing that it wont work initially.

Comment: Your #ifdef will not help prevent multiple executions of init_some_hw_peripherals(). The are evaluated before the program is compiled not at runtime.

Comment: `#define`s, and `#ifndef`s does know about a concept of "functions". Why a `private` variable can't be used for this purpose?

Comment: ***I would appreciate if you could help me manage this situation and give me some guidance.*** Use a bool variable. Set it to false in your constructor. When init_some_hw_peripherals() is called set it to true. Check if it is true when you execute perform()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use private member to tell you if initialization was done or not:

```
class myClass {
public:
    myClass() : isInit(false) {}
    ...
private:
    bool isInit;
};

void myClass::init(void)
{
    if (!init) {
      init_some_hw_peripherals();
      init = true;
    }
}

void myClass::perform (void)
{
    if (!init) {
        cout << "You havent initialized. Use myClass::init()";
    } else {
      doPerform();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach for me is that I have several classes that may call the init function. So I do not want to make it a private variable. That is why I stick with this kind of solution, knowing that it wont work initially.

Comment: @mozcelikors This will still work, regardless of how the `init` function is called.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. This is certainly one solution since init is a class object. I'll wait for some others if anybody else has any more ideas. Eventually, I'll choose the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the presence of `init`-like functions indicates a lack of proper constructor. The given requirements clearly lead to two classes with dedicated constructors:

```
class hwPeripherals
{
      private: static ::std::atomic_bool s_construction_attempted;

      // instead of init_some_hw_peripherals
      public: hwPeripherals(void)
      {
          // Check that no attempts of hwPeripherals construction happened yet.
          if(s_construction_attempted.exchange(true))
          {
               // Throw an exception.
          }
          // Initialization... Throw an exception if fails.
      }
};

class myClass
{
     private: myClass(void) = delete;

     // instead of init
     public: explicit myClass(hwPeripherals & peripherals)
     {
          // Initialization... Throw an exception if fails.
     }

     public: void perform(void);
};
```

This way to call perform user will need to instantiate `myClass` first, and it order to do this user will need to instantiate `hwPeripherals`:

```
hwPeripherals peripherals{};
myClass obj{peripherals};
obj.perform();
```